# How to convert JSON to another type with SwiftJSON

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I try to get json data form web services with Alamofire + SwiftJSON but I can not convert type JSON to another type

My code

```
 var product:JSON = []

 override func viewDidLoad() 

 { Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in 
   if json != nil { 
   self.product = JSON(json!) 
   let data = self.product["product"] 
    self.product = JSON(data!)
```

I want json data in to product:[NSDictionary] for dispay title name or id in my collectionViewCell . Please some advise. –

Json data response

```
{ 
  "product":{ 
  "title":"Night Cream", 
  "id":4573, 
  "created_at":"2015-08-21T07:54:09Z", 
  "updated_at":"2015-08-27T01:37:06Z", 
} 
}
```

How do I convert data (type JSON) to dictionary in order to apply for a future use?

Comment: What is the _real_ problem? Can't you just write some code to convert it? Without knowing your requirement (expected output), this question is not answerable.

Comment: Problem is how can i convert data  to NSDictionary. When I try to " let data = jsonObj["product".dictionary it not working. How can I do it sir.

Comment: First, you don't want to convert it to NSDictionary. Second, define "not working". Post the code and error message here will help. It will be even better if you actually read the error message and try to understand it.

Comment: My code  

var product:[NSDictionary] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {

Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in 
if json != nil { 
var jsonObj = JSON(json!) 
let data = jsonObj["product"] 

self.product = data  // Cannot assign a value of type [String:JSON]? to a value of type [NSDictionary] // error message

I want json data in to product:[NSDictionary] for dispay  title name or id in my collectionViewCell . Please some advise.

Comment: You should edit your question instead of put code in comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
var product:[String:JSON] = [String:JSON]()

    override func viewDidLoad() 
         {
              Alamofire.request(YOUR_URL, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding:  URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
                     switch(response.result) 
                     {
                    case .success(_):
                         let dict = JSON(response.result.value ?? "").dictionaryValue
                         self.product=dict["product"].dictionaryValue
                             break
                    case .failure(_):
                        // The network connection was lost please try again
                        break
                     }
                }
        }
```

Follow above code to get your solution